# Copy a column from a file to be the first column in another file

Tags: linux

I want to copy a column from file to be the first column in another file contains many columns. How can I do that using the command line?

file 1 as

```
1
2
2
-
-
```

file 2 as

```
2  5
3  5
3  5
-  -
-  -
```

I want fil3 as

```
1 2  5
2 3  5
2 3  5
- -  -
- -  -
```

Comment: [`paste file1 file2`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/paste)

Comment: file 1, file 2, and file 3 are columns, not rows.

Comment: how can I define spaces between columns in the final file.

Comment: "define spaces" - what do you mean by that? Space is a space, it's already [defined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_(punctuation)). (?) Please post example input and expected output.

Comment: I mean make between first and second columns two spaces, second and fourth columns three spaces

Comment: `fourth columns` - there is no fourth column in the samples you posted. Also this is a separate problem, as separate question.

Comment: sorry I mean second and three columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a perfect job for `paste`:

```
$ paste -d' ' file1 file2
1 2  5
2 3  5
2 3  5
- -  -
- -  -
```

The `-d' '` uses a space to separate the two lines; this is needed because `paste` uses a tab by default.

Comment: That's a full 50 characters shorter than an `awk` solution.

Comment: Thanks, now how can I define spaces between columns in the final file.